# Selecting the (number of) columns dyanamically using linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table like this

```
    Student   Exam    p1   p2   p3   p4   p5   p6   p7   p8   p9   p10   p11   p12
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    100       unit1   89   56   59   28   48   38   0    0    0     0     0     0
    100       unit2   89   56   59   0     0    0   0    0    0     0     0     0
    100       unit3   89   56   59   28   48   38   0    0    0     0     0     0
    100       unit4   89   56   59   28   48   0    0    0    0     0     0     0
```

another table

```
    Exam   Num_subjects
    ----------------------
    unit1     6
    unit2     3
    unit3     6
    unit4     5
```

now i need to select the only first 8 columns in the marks table for unit1 as the number of subject for the unit1 is 6 .. how to do this dynamically ...
exam is foreign key to the marks table in linq to sql any ideas ...

Comment: What's wrong with selecting all the columns, but simply not using those you don't need?

Comment: @lain i must append it to a grid dynamically so it will populate all the columns in the grid..

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column based design, since L2S doesn't let you manually materialize (i.e. `new MyTable { Foo = row.Foo /* omit some }` you are a bit scuppered.

If you **just** want the data, you could use something like "dapper" which won't have this issue, but you'll need to write the TSQL yourself, i.e.

```
var rows = conn.Query<MyTable>("select p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 from MyTable where Exam=@exam",
        new { exam }).ToList();
```

But ultimately, I think I'd prefer a different db schema here...

Answer (score 0):

there would be no need for a dynamic query, if those tables were normalized. (check your design)

if you *really* want to do this dynamically, you'll need an expression tree that handles the select part of your query ... [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) you can find some more details about a dynamic query lib that can handle that expression tree generation for you (you can provide a string like "new(p1,p2,p3)" and that gets translated to an expression tree)

Comment: @diamond well, in that case i'd try to live with that 0 or NULL values in my datamodel, and omit them when it comes to displaying stuff, or if really necessary use the lib mentioned above and have an anonymous type with the desired fields (you would still have to generate a comma separated string containing the field list, but that's rather easy)

Answer (score 0):

Here you don't need to use linq, you can do it with logic

Now just get Num_Subjects like for unit1 = 6

```
DataTable dt = [whole_table];

int counter = Num_Subjects + 1; //7

string colName = "P" + counter.ToString(); //P7

while(dt.Columns.Contains(colName))
{
   dt.Columns.Remove(colName);
   colName = "P" + (++counter).ToString()
}
```

At last you we get a table upto P6 columns rest of columns will be deleted.